# How can I run a command before executing tests with both `dotnet test` and VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, automated-tests

I have a .NET project which depends on a database that I am writing integration tests for. When I run the tests I need a local docker container to be running. It can be started using the following command (from the solution root):

```sh
docker compose up -d db
```

For now, this is simple enough to do manually but, ideally, standing up the container would be automated whenever the tests are run. To this end I tried the adding following:

`(solution root)/Directory.Build.props`:

```xml
<SolutionRoot>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))</SolutionRoot>
```

`(solution root)/tests/IntegrationTests/IntegrationTests.csproj`:

```xml
  <Target Name="DbContainerUp" BeforeTargets="VSTest">
    <Exec Command="cd $(SolutionRoot)" />
    <Exec Command="docker compose up -d db" />
  </Target>
```

This works *but only when executed via `dotnet test`*. If I execute the tests using either Visual Studio Test Explorer or VSCode Test Runner then the `DbContainerUp` target is not invoked. I assume this is because the Test Explorer/Runner does not invoke `dotnet msbuild /t:VSTest` (which is what `dotnet test` is translated to) but I am unable to find any documentation of what targets (if any) VS and VSCode use.

I have looked into the following and not found a viable path forward yet:

1. `.runsettings` does not provide an extensibility point for executing commands.
2. [The xunit runner source](https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit) doesn't contain a custom target.

Answer (score 1):

For now I have solved this by adding an `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"` attribute to the `DbContainerUp` target like so:

```xml
  <Target Name="DbContainerUp" BeforeTargets="VSTest" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="cd $(SolutionRoot)" />
    <Exec Command="docker compose up -d db" />
  </Target>
```

This works because VS (and VS Code) must build the `IntegrationTests` project as part of either test discovery or prior to test execution (depending on implementation). Additionally, because `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets` are cooperative (either will trigger the custom target), this means that `dotnet test` continues to behave as expected.

While this isn't a perfect solution--any generic `dotnet build` will also start the container--it is acceptable for our needs to ensure the container is started.